# JSX Script : the prompt isn't showing up

Tags: javascript, json, jsx, adobe, adobe-illustrator

Hey there I'm making a script to export JSON file from Adobe Illustrator

```
// Helper function to export prefixed objects
function exportPrefixedObjects(doc) {
  // get prefixes and reference point as input from user
  var prefixInput = prompt("Enter the Prefixes seperated by commas","btn_,dlg_");
  var referencePointInput = prompt("Enter the reference point for each prefix seperated by commas","center,top_left");
  var prefixes = {}
  var prefixArr = prefixInput.split(',')
  var referenceArr = referencePointInput.split(',')
  
  for(var i=0; i<prefixArr.length; i++){
      prefixes[prefixArr[i]] = referenceArr[i]
  }

  const prefixedObjects = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < doc.layers.length; i++) {
    const layer = doc.layers[i];
    const name = layer.name;

    // Check if the layer name starts with a prefix
    for (var prefix in prefixes) {
      if (name.startsWith(prefix)) {
        // Get the reference point
        const referencePoint = prefixes[prefix];

        // Get the position of the layer
        const pos = layer.position;

        // Get the width and height of the layer
        const width = layer.width;
        const height = layer.height;

        // Create an object with the layer's info
        const obj = {
          name: name,
          x: pos[0],
          y: pos[1],
          referencePoint: referencePoint,
          width: width,
          height: height
        };
        prefixedObjects.push(obj);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return prefixedObjects;
}

// Helper function to get artboard info
function getArtboardInfo(artboard) {
  return {
    name: artboard.name,
    origin: {
      x: artboard.rulerOrigin[0],
      y: artboard.rulerOrigin[1]
    }
  };
}

// Get the active document and the selected artboard
const doc = app.activeDocument;
const selectedArtboard = doc.artboards[doc.artboards.getActiveArtboardIndex()];

// Get the array of prefixed objects and their info
const prefixedObjects = exportPrefixedObjects(doc);

// Get the artboard info
const artboardInfo = getArtboardInfo(selectedArtboard);

// Append the artboard info to each prefixed object
prefixedObjects.forEach(obj => {
  obj.artboardName = artboardInfo.name;
  obj.artboardOrigin = artboardInfo.origin;
});

// Convert the array of objects to a JSON string
const jsonString = JSON.stringify(prefixedObjects);

// Save the JSON file
const file = new File(doc.path + '/prefixed-objects.json');
file.open('w');
file.write(jsonString);
file.close();
```

The problem here is that to prompt() Function is not showing up so he gives an error and when I checked that was because

prefixedObjects

doesn't have any values (sure cause there is no prompt to enter the values)

I don't know what should I do

Comment: Do you mean prompt is not working in the terminal?

Comment: there is a window that should pop up so u can enter the values

Answer (score 0):

Illustrator's Extendscript is the outdated old version of Javascript. ES3 or ES4 generation. There is no `forEach`, `map`, `filter` array methods, etc. So you can change the lines:

```
prefixedObjects.forEach(obj => {
  obj.artboardName = artboardInfo.name;
  obj.artboardOrigin = artboardInfo.origin;
});
```

with a classic loop. For example a loop 'for':

```
for (var i=0; i<prefixedObjects.length; i++) {
  var obj = prefixedObjects[i];
  obj.artboardName = artboardInfo.name;
  obj.artboardOrigin = artboardInfo.origin;
}
```